# Mysql Query Understanding

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quick question about how to query this information

So let's say in my database I have topics of

```
Welcome Center    Group 1
Members Questions Group 2
Admin Ops         Group 3
```

and a users table of

```
User 1      Group 1
User 2      Group 2
User 3      Group 3
```

and a group tables of

```
1     Register User  
2     Member 
3     Admin
```

Okay so that would be something like a database, now say I only want register a user with a group 1 to see Items with group 1.

```
"SELECT * FROM topic WHERE group = 1"
```

So they can't see the stuff for the member's and admin's.

This is where the problem starts.

I need to find a query where, or learn away that we allow the member to see the registered users topic and the members topic.

```
"SELECT * FROM topic WHERE group = 1 AND group = 2"
```

As you can see this an example and not sure if this is what I need to do.

Same with Admins, I need them to be able to see the registered user topics, member topics, and the admin topics. So all three.

```
"SELECT * FROM topic WHERE group = 1 AND group = 2 AND group = 3"
```

As you can see that I am not one hundred percent sure that this will work, before I waste my time coding something that isn't going to be like this but the query is where I am kinda stuck at.

Comment: Maybe you'd better waste some time coding and then ask for help with your code if it does not work.

Comment: Group is a reserved word. Perhaps there's something you're not telling us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all topics that have both groups, then use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT t.topic
FROM topic t
GROUP BY t.topic
HAVING SUM(group = 1) > 0 AND
       SUM(group = 2) > 0;
```

Note that `group` is a bad name for a column because it is a reserved word.